# what does && { command } in bash do?

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand this snippet

```
[[ ${FLAGS:-} =~ s ]] && {
    screen -ls|grep -Eq "[0-9]+\.${name}" && {
      _log "INFO: killing java process $name"
      jps -l | egrep "target/.*${name}" |cut -f1 -d ' '|xargs kill
    }
    return 0
  }
```

I want to kill java process that matches the `${name}` variable, but the command never executes. `${FLAGS}` should be equivalent to `s`. I don't quite understand why I need to run

```
screen -ls|grep -Eq "[0-9]+\.${name}"
```

before the kill command. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: What does the snippet's author say about it?

Comment: That's some very nasty code. I'd strongly suggest replacing it with real process supervision -- which, in modern Linux, means setting up a systemd service to supervise your process.

Comment: ...that said, it smells like your _real_ question isn't really about what `&& { ...block of code...; }` does (which is exactly the same as what `&& simplecommand` does, except running all the commands in the stated block); instead, this reads as a request to _debug_ that very unnecessarily gnarly scriptlet.

Comment: I will close the question if you don't think it's valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A && B` means, roughly, execute `A`, and if, and only if, it terminates normally with a successful termination status, then execute `B`.

Comment: This helped me figure out the issue `screen -ls|grep -Eq "[0-9]+\.${name}"` was not executing properly which caused the subsequent command to fail.